# Store 2-dimensional array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array

I have to store array of attributes:

```
   | attr-1 | attr-2 | ...... | attr-n
---------------------------------------
 A | val-A1 | val-A2 | ...... | val-An
---------------------------------------
 B | val-B1 | val-B2 | ...... | val-Bn
```

Now, I'm doing this in that way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSDictionary *A =
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:val-A1,
                                      val-A2,
                                      ......,
                                      val-An, nil]
                                    forKeys:
            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"attr-1",
                                      @"attr-2",
                                      .........,
                                      @"attr-n", nil]];

NSDictionary *B =
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:val-B1,
                                      val-B2,
                                      ......,
                                      val-Bn, nil]
                                    forKeys:
            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"attr-1",
                                      @"attr-2",
                                      .........,
                                      @"attr-n", nil]];

[attributes setObject:A forKey:@"A"];
[attributes setObject:B forKey:@"B"];
```

It's a lot of coding. Anyone knows better solution?

PS. Values don't change.

Comment: You could use the newish Objective-C literal syntax.

Comment: Do you actually need nested dictionaries, or would nested `NSArray`s do just as well?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps

```
NSDictionary *A = @{ @"attr-1" : @1, @"attr-2" : @2 };
NSDictionary *B = @{ @"attr-1" : @4, @"attr-2" : @5 };
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [@{ @"A" : A, @"B" : B } mutableCopy];
```

You could then retrieve the `5` with code like this

```
NSNumber *number = attributes[@"B"][@"attr-2"];
NSLog( @"%d", number.intValue );
```